# How to read encrypted values from Quarkus config properties?

Tags: configuration-files, quarkus

I'm setting up my Quarkus app to run in the cloud, but I couldn't find how to handle encrypted properties in the configuration file.

In my Spring Boot apps I know that I can prefix a property with some tags so it'll be decrypted before usage:

```
password={cipher}{key:alias}<encrypted-text>
```

Is there any Quarkus AWS plugin that handles such syntax?

Or any way that I can access the configuration properties before usage so I decrypt them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Quarkus. There are some prototype to support something similar in the future but they are not complete yet. Please follow: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7442

The recommendation is to Vault: https://quarkus.io/guides/vault

If you want to access configuration before usage, you can implement an interceptor: https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/main/interceptors/interceptors.html

Comment: Hi, Roberto, thank you for your answer. I managed to achieve what I want by implementing a custom CredentialsProvider (https://quarkus.io/guides/credentials-provider). Considering the configuration interceptor you mentioned and the CredentialsProvider, would you say one solution is better than the other?

Comment: Either works, is just a matter of preference :)